# Oracle performance when updating millions of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update almost 800 millions of rows and searching the best approach.
I already tried to use bulk collection and update, but take to long.
I commit after every 5000 records.
For 130 min. I have only 0.25% ready, so I am searching another way.
The structure of table is

```
CAMP_TASK                        NUMBER             
CODE_SYSTEM                      VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)  
ID_SOURCE                        VARCHAR2(40 CHAR)  
ID_SOURCE_PARENT                 VARCHAR2(40 CHAR)  
DATE_EFFECTIVE                   DATE               
PROC_INSERTED                    NUMBER             
PROC_UPDATED                     NUMBER             
CAMP_TASK_PARENT                 NUMBER
```

and I have to update `camp_task_parent` field with camp_task value if id_source_parent is not null. So in other words if a have id_source_parent I have find his corresponding cam_task and update camp_task_parent with it for the current rowed.

Thanks!

Comment: do you actually really need to do it in one single big transaction ?

Comment: well, I commit after every 5000 records

Comment: please, show the table definition, and what column do you need to update and are there any where conditions?

Comment: FYI 0 https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022

Comment: what is the structure of the table and what is the update you're doing, if you give more information we can give you a better advice.

Comment: Another way is to create a new table by selecting the data you want e.g. `create table new_data as select a,b,c*2,d, e-42 from old_data;` Then drop the old table rename the new one to replace the old one; add constraints indexes etc.  Sounds drastic, but so is trying to update 800M rows!

Comment: What's the problem with "too slow"? Run it over the weekend, and it'll be done by Monday.

Comment: So about 800 million of the records in the table have an ID_SOURCE_PARENT? Why do you have to update the values when you can always read them from the other table? Is it just for convenient access? Then maybe a view would suffice.

Comment: if you don't mind, please let us know how long the process finally took

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the fastest way would be to

1) create new empty table with the same structure

```
create table new_table as select * from old_table where 1=2;
```

2) disable logging for that table so that you won't run out of recovery
    area space

```
alter table new_table nologging;
```

3) populate new table with updated records, bypassing constraints,
    triggers and the buffer cache

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into new_table (select <update column expressions> from old_table);
```

4) **double-check data is migrated correctly**

5) clean up

```
 drop old_table;
 alter table new_table logging;
 rename new_table to old_table;
```

6) re-create indexes

7) **backup database**

Comment: And if you have resources; CPU and IO Bandwidth, you can employ parallelism too.